# Trying to import data from excel file into RDS MySQL table and it takes too long to insert

Tags: python, mysql, import, rds

I am trying to import data from an excel sheet int MySQL table using python. I have around 250 files in a folder that I want to import to MySQL. Code works and imports data but it takes too long for each file.

```
import xlrd
import MySQLdb
import os
import glob
database=MySQLdb.connect()
for filepath in glob.iglob('folder\\*.xlsx')
path=filepath
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    cursor=database.cursor()
    query="""insert into tx_shape_files(col1,col2,...col6) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    for r in range(1,sheet.nrows):

        col1=sheet.cell(r,0).value
        col2=sheet.cell(r,1).value
        col3=sheet.cell(r,2).value
        col4=sheet.cell(r,3).value
        col5=sheet.cell(r,4).value
        col6=sheet.cell(r,5).value
        values=(col1,col2,...col6)

        cursor.execute(query,values)
    cursor.close()
    database.commit()

    print("Done")
    columns=str(sheet.ncols)
    rows=str(sheet.nrows)
    print("Imported " +columns+ " columns and "+ rows+" rows to MYSQL")
database.close()
```

This code takes too long to import data to from excel to RDS MySql database.

Please help me optimize my code.

Comment: 1) How many rows are you inserting? 2) Where are you running this code? 3) How long is "too long"?

Comment: i have around 250 excel files in a folder. Each file has anywhere between 50-50,000 rows . I am running this python code through command line. The first file has 5000 rows and it takes more than 15 mins, the second file has 22000 rows, it takes more than 30 mins. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit db only one time. You can insert multiple row in single insert statement as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9);
```

Execute cursor.execute() statement outside the inner for loop to execute the query with multiple row at once. Adding code for reference.

```
import xlrd
import MySQLdb
import os
import glob
database=MySQLdb.connect()
for filepath in glob.iglob('folder\\*.xlsx')
path=filepath
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    cursor=database.cursor()
    query="""insert into tx_shape_files(col1,col2,...col6) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
    all_values = []
    for r in range(1,sheet.nrows):

        col1=sheet.cell(r,0).value
        col2=sheet.cell(r,1).value
        col3=sheet.cell(r,2).value
        col4=sheet.cell(r,3).value
        col5=sheet.cell(r,4).value
        col6=sheet.cell(r,5).value
        values=(col1,col2,...col6)
        all_values.append(values)

    cursor.execute(query, all_values)
    cursor.close()
    database.commit()

    print("Done")
    columns=str(sheet.ncols)
    rows=str(sheet.nrows)
    print("Imported " +columns+ " columns and "+ rows+" rows to MYSQL")
database.close()
```

Comment: I am trying to do this..cursor=database.cursor()
 complete_table=[]
 query="""insert into tx_shape_files(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
 for r in range(1,sheet.nrows):

  col1=sheet.cell(r,0).value
  col2=sheet.cell(r,1).value
  col3=sheet.cell(r,2).value
  col4=sheet.cell(r,3).value
  col5=sheet.cell(r,4).value
  col6=sheet.cell(r,5).value
  values=(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6)
  complete_table.append(values)
 cursor.execute(query,[complete_table])
 It throws  not enough arguments for format string error. how do i fix it?

Comment: don't place complete_table inside [ ]. complete_table is a list object. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Joshi.. I did that first and it throws this error                
 query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting